# vbscript to kill IE and restart with screensaver

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, restart

I have the following VBscript which is suppose to kill IE and restart it in Kiosk mode once it sees a process in the tasklist.
It looks like the code goes through the first time, and starts IE, but after that it doesn't kill/start IE.

Is there something wrong with my loop?
Thank you in advance.

```
'SCRIPT purpose: Reset IE into Kiosk mode once Screensaver comes on.
'UPDATED: 02/06/18



OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM strComputer,strProcess,strProcess2, restartFlag
DIM oshell : set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strComputer = "." ' local computer
strProcess = "SnapSCR.scr"
restartFlag = true

DO While true
    IF isProcessRunning(strComputer,strProcess) THEN
        IF restartFlag = true THEN
            oShell.Run "taskkill /im iexplore.exe",, True
            oShell.Run "iexplore.exe -k",,True
            restartFlag = false
        ELSE    
            restartFlag = false
        End if
    ELSE 
        restartFlag = true
    END IF
    WScript.Sleep 10000
LOOP


' Function to check if a process is running
FUNCTION isProcessRunning(BYVAL strComputer,BYVAL strProcessName)

    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery

    strWMIQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process where name like '" & strProcessName & "'"

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 



IF objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0 THEN
        isProcessRunning = TRUE
    ELSE
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
END IF


END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this vbscript can did the trick :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ScreenSaverName
ScreenSaverName = "SnapSCR.scr"
If AppPrevInstance() Then  
    MsgBox "There is an instance already in progress" & vbCrlf &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,_
    "There is an instance already in progress"  
    WScript.Quit  
Else  
    Do
        Call CheckProcess(DblQuote(ScreenSaverName))
        Call Pause(10)
    Loop 
End If  
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,WshShell,Tab,ProcessName
    strComputer = "."
    Tab = Split(ProcessPath,"\")
    ProcessName = Tab(UBound(Tab))
    ProcessName = Replace(ProcessName,Chr(34),"")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& ProcessName & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "taskkill /im iexplore.exe",0,True
        WshShell.Run "iexplore.exe -k",1,True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End if
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
'Function to add double quotes in a variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub  
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()  
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")  
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName))  
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)  
        End With  
    End With  
End Function 
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you for the code improvements.  It kind of works.  If IE is not running, when the screensaver launches, IE does get launched.  Now if IE is running, and the Screensaver launches again, IE doesn't close and start.  I have a processor monitor running, so I know for sure the SnapScr.scr runs.  Please provide additional help if possible.  Thank you again.